# Laravel Query Builder inherit where of the other var

Tags: laravel-5.1

I am with Laravel 5.1, I have this:

```
$q = Model::where('tipo','<>','');
```

then I do:

```
$res1 = $q->where('value','>',1)->get();
$res2 = $q->where('value','>',2)->get();
```

Then `$res2` have inherit the where of `$res1` too?

what can be the problem??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check **Laravel Query Scope**

**Query Scope** will allow you to easily re-use query. Add the query scope function inside your model. Simply prefix a model method with scope:

***In Model:***

```
public function scopeFirstCondition($query)
{
    return $query->where('value','>',1);
}

public function scopeSecondCondition($query)
{
    return $query->where('value','>',2);
}
```

Then you can fetch the values likewise:

```
$res1 = Model::firstCondition()->get();
$res2 = Model::secondCondition()->get();
```

If required you could also combine them:

```
$result = Model::firstCondition()->secondCondition()->get();
```

Docs: [Laravel Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes)

Hope this is Helpful.

Comment: If I need a "pre-filter" before, like $q = Model::where('tipo','<>','') ?

Comment: Yes, you can pass parameters to the query scope method and you can process that parameter within your model scope method.